# How to make timedelta into string

Tags: python, time, strftime, timedelta

im using T1-T2 in order to take the time delta and then i want to make it back into string
I've trying the following code

```
layover_info = datetime.strptime(leg_info['dep_time'], '%H:%M') - start_waiting_time
layover_info_str = layover_info.strftime('%H:%M')
```

but it doesnt work.. im getting the error

```
error: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: You will need to format it manually, `timedelta` objects don't have `strftime` (which is exactly what the error tells you...)

Comment: so how do i format it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually, something like this:

```
def my_strftime(layover_info):
   hours, remainder = divmod(layover_info.seconds, 3600)
   minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
   print '%02s:%02s' % (hours, minutes)

layover_info = datetime.strptime(leg_info['dep_time'], '%H:%M') -     start_waiting_time
layover_info_str = my_strftime(layover_info)
```